Difference between "Port VLAN ID" and "Untagged VLAN Membership" on HP Aruba Switches
I think I understood VLANs pretty well by now but I struggle with PVID (Port VLAN ID) versus untagged VLAN Membership.
What is the difference between these two? Why would I want to configure a port with different values? (I notice, when I assign Untagged VLAN Port Membership, the PVID is set / altered accordingly. But I can change the PVID afterwards to be different from the untagged VLAN Membership. Even to a number outside my defined VLANs!) Just why?
I work with a Aruba Instant On 1830 24G 2SFP Switch JL812A


The terminology is a bit confusing but PVID is basically you allow interface 21 to act as a trunk for VLAN 99 that is handled elsewhere, while any device connected directly to interface 21 will be treated as belonging to VLAN 8.

I don't know much about VLAN, but I think PVID is about untagged ingress traffics, meaning that untagged traffics that goes into the switch via interface 21 will be forwarded to interfaces that belong to VLAN 99. Untagged VLAN and Tagged VLANs are about egress traffics, meaning that traffics from VLAN 8 that leaves the switch via / are forwarded to interface 21 would be untagged. (I feel like if the PVID isn't in Untagged VLAN or Tagged VLANs, traffics from the corresponding VLAN will not be forwarded to this interface. In other words, together they define which VLANs an interface belongs to.)

(Or perhaps the PVID would be implicitly added to the list of Tagged VLANs if it is not declared as the Untagged VLAN. In Linux if you add a bridge port to a VLAN, you can also set the pvid and untagged attributes for that entry. If you set only pvid but not untagged, then for that port the VLAN ID would be considered the PVID and the VLAN will be considerd a Tagged VLAN, as per the behavior/definition I described above. Although in Linux it seems that you can have multiple Untagged VLANs for a port, while at max one VLAN ID can be the PVID of a port.)

@TomYan yes, the distinction seems to be ingress and egress. I found this old post where the answer constructs a case where it could be useful to handle ingress and egress frames differently. But at this point in my professional life I can hardly imagine ever using this.
